# What is use of LookupMulti in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column

Can somebody tell me what is the use of LookupMulti in Sharepoint 2013 and how to implement this with visual studio 2012?

Can we use this for chaining purpose ?

For example, I have 2 lists country and states. 
If I select one country, for eg India, then will it show me the states from India only? If I select particular state then it should show me cities in that state only? Is it possible with LookupMulti?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multilookup field is a column that points to another list, and allows you to enter multiple items into the current item from that list.

It will not give you cascading/filtered lookups like you want. You need to do that in [InfoPath](http://koobarspoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/cascading-drop-downs-with-infopath-2010.html), [JavaScript](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation), or write your own code to do that.

This [blog post](http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2007-30-cascading-lookup.html) has many references to help with cascading dropdowns.